# Having problems displaying favicon in codeigniter. Title shows the code instead

Tags: html, codeigniter, title, favicon

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo base_url().'favicon.ico'?>">Project name</title>
```

I have placed favicon.ico in the root folder.
But when trying to browse the page title shows the code instead with the entire link tag.
Lost of ideas on what to do.

Comment: Cache cleared ?

Comment: yes sir cache cleared.

Comment: Try solutions from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1:

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>favicon.ico"> <title>Project Name. </title>
```

Turn's out OP wrapped  into `<title></title>`, which causing it not working.

### Solution 2:

put your favicon.ico to your project root folder, then use `href="favicon.ico"`

Comment: Tried both with no luck. Do I need to make some configuration changes?

Comment: @AmanMishra ok try this `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/favicon.ico">Project name</title>`

Comment: @AmanMishra take a look at this one, make sure you are not missing anything https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_link_sizes

Comment: Ok, So I separated the title and link and it worked.    <link rel="icon"  href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>favicon.ico">
     <title>Project Name.
    </title>

Comment: Please edit the answer so I can accept it. Thanks a ton Daniel

Comment: @AmanMishra hm, <link> are self closing, didn't notice that you have wraped the link into title, good to know lol!